# why Cuda not detected by hashcat?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have the following graphices cards installed in my workstation

```
Thu Aug 18 19:22:51 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   39C    P8     7W / 200W |    118MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   36C    P8     5W / 190W |      6MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   39C    P8     6W / 190W |      6MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

when I try to benchmark using `hashcat -b` I get  this

```
hashcat (v6.2.5) starting in benchmark mode

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default.
You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option.
Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length.
To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

ATTENTION! No OpenCL-compatible, HIP-compatible or CUDA-compatible platform found.
```

I tried to install different drivers  and i tried to manully download the driver using executable but nothing seems to fix this issue

the output of `lspci | grep "GTX"`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
```

The output of `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01
  Device-3: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    gpu: nvidia,nvidia,nvidia resolution: 1920x1080~50Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.5
```

The output of `lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Please [edit] your questoin and add the specific operating system you are using (you have tagged with Ubuntu, if that's what you are using, please add it to your question and include the version). Also show us the output of `inxi -G` (if you don't have it, you can install `inxi` on Debian-based systems with `apt install inxi`).

Comment: @terdon please check the updated question

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I can't really help, though, I just wanted the info because it will probably help someone who knows more than I do and who can help.